NotMapped Attribute is ignored when used on List of object
I have this model:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyProject.Class.Dto;

namespace SageApi.Model;

public partial class FArticle
{
    public string ArRef { get; set; } = null!;

    [NotMapped]
    public int? Prices { get; set; }

    public static void ConfigureModelBuilder(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<FArticle>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ArRef, "UKA_F_ARTICLE_AR_Ref").IsUnique();
            entity.Property(e => e.ArRef)
                .HasMaxLength(19)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("AR_Ref");
        });
    }
}

I'm using HotChocolate Query to get my data with GraphQl:
using SageApi.Model.Sage;

namespace SageApi.Services.GraphQl;
public class Query
{
    [UseOffsetPaging(MaxPageSize = 100, IncludeTotalCount = true, DefaultPageSize = 20)]
    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public IEnumerable<FArticle> GetFArticles([Service] SageDbContext context) =>
        context.FArticles;
}

When I launch my query:
{
    fArticles(
        skip: 0
        take: 1
    ) {
        items {
            arRef
            prices
        }
    }
}

It works fine prices has the value null.
Now I create a Dto:
namespace SageApi.Class.Dto;

public class PriceDto
{
    public short? SomeValue { get; set; }
}

and I change
    [NotMapped]
    public int? Prices { get; set; }

to
    [NotMapped]
    public IList<PriceDto>? Prices { get; set; }

Now when I launch the query
{
    fArticles(
        skip: 0
        take: 1
    ) {
        items {
            arRef
            prices{
                someValue
            }
        }
    }
}

I got error:
The LINQ expression 'p1 => new PriceDto{ SomeValue = p1.SomeValue }
' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Why does Dotnet try to get SomeValue in the database while I clearly specify the [NotMapped] attribute ? This problem doesn't occur when Prices is a String or Int (not an object).
What am I missing here ?
Edit
Also adding NotMapped to class GrillePriceDto like so, does not solve the issue:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SageApi.Class.Dto;

[NotMapped]
public class PriceDto
{
    public short? SomeValue { get; set; }
}

Also adding entity.Ignore(e => e.Prices); in modelBuilder like so, does not solve the issue:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyProject.Class.Dto;

namespace SageApi.Model;

public partial class FArticle
{
    public string ArRef { get; set; } = null!;

    [NotMapped]
    public IList<PriceDto>? Prices { get; set; }

    public static void ConfigureModelBuilder(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<FArticle>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ArRef, "UKA_F_ARTICLE_AR_Ref").IsUnique();
            entity.Property(e => e.ArRef)
                .HasMaxLength(19)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("AR_Ref");
            entity.Ignore(e => e.Prices);
        });
    }
}

Edit 2
Minimal reproductible example: https://github.com/Lenny4/NotMappedAttributeListObject

have you tried adding not mapped to the DTO ? It might be checking in an order from primitive type and then upwards. You can also try adding a not mapped configuration for the property in the builder.

Hi @terodaktil just tried to add NotMapped and to use entity.Ignore as shown in the Edit and it does not solve the issue. When you say try adding a not mapped configuration for the property in the builder did you think of  entity.Ignore as in my Edit or something else ?

Have you tried making query only for prices (i.e. something like items {prices} for the first case)?

My guess would be that GraphQL will generate query for EF Core based on the requested props, since you are requesting all of them potentially something like dbContext.FArticles.Skip().Take().ToArray or similar in effect is generated (which results in select *), while for the collection some kind of explicit expansion is generated (like Select( p => new PriceDto{...} ) ) which can't be translated since the property is not mapped.  Can you please provide a [mre] to play with? Where the data for prices should come from?

No idea why that is not working. Although i am not really familiar with GraphQL. What you can try from the EF side is to try and add IgnoreAutoIncludes() which disables eager loading for that linq query. I don't know how your project is set up, but you can try adding this builder configurations in the OnModelCreating in AppDbContext. maybe they are being overwritten there. The issue might be due to the missing column, i assume here that the table FArticle does not have an empty column for prices, adding a default null for prices might do something.

Also try calling var smth = context.FArticles; in a separate line to isolate it from GraphQL see if that passes. Calling context.FArticles.Select(x => x.ARref).ToList(); will solve your current issue but not the underlying ignore problem. Or you will have to write something like :
var smth = (from article in context.FArticles
select article).ToList(); // This should Not pass
var articles = (from article in context.FArticles
select new FArticle()
{
ArRef = article.ArRef
}).ToList(); // This should pass

@GuruStron I couldn't find a way to make it work, so I created a minimalist reproductible example: https://github.com/Lenny4/NotMappedAttributeListObject

@terodaktil I don't know how to use IgnoreAutoIncludes, I created a minimalist reproductible example: https://github.com/Lenny4/NotMappedAttributeListObject

@GuruStron the data for price are set with a middleware https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/execution-engine/field-middleware#usage-as-an-attribute I did not include the middleware in the example as it is not needed to reproduce the error

It's not related to EF and based on the Hotchocolate document you need to exclude the property:

Exclude fields:
If a projected field is requested, the whole subtree is processed. Sometimes you want to opt out of projections. The projections middleware skips a field in two cases. Either the visitor encounters a field that is a UseProjection field itself, or it defines IsProjected(false).

Link: https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/fetching-data/projections#exclude-fields
So I could run your app successfully with this config:
public class FArticle
{
    public int CbMarq { get; set; }

    [IsProjected(true)] public string ArRef { get; set; } = null!;

    //Exclude by using: IsProjected(false)
    [IsProjected(false)][NotMapped] public IList<PriceDto>? Prices { get; set; }

    public static void ConfigureModelBuilder(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<FArticle>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.CbMarq).HasName("PK_CBMARQ_F_ARTICLE");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ArRef, "UKA_F_ARTICLE_AR_Ref").IsUnique();
            entity.Property(e => e.ArRef)
                .HasMaxLength(19)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("AR_Ref");

            entity.Ignore(e => e.Prices);
        });
    }
} 


Adding [IsProjected(false)] on Prices and adding [NotMapped] on PriceDto solve the issue

You can ignore any fields in GraphQL by using the attribute [GraphQLIgnore]
public interface IMessage
{
    [GraphQLIgnore]
    User Author { get; set; }

    DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

Or using interfaceType
public class MessageType : InterfaceType<IMessage>
{
    protected override void Configure(
        IInterfaceTypeDescriptor<IMessage> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Ignore(f => f.Author);
    }
}

Refer: https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v12/defining-a-schema/interfaces#including-fields

I'm not trying to ignore the Prices field
